# How to build a recurrent neural net in Keras where each input goes through a layer first?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to build an neural net in Keras that would look like this:

[image]

Where *x_1*, *x_2*, ... are input vectors that undergo the same transformation *f*. *f* is itself a layer whose parameters must be learned. The sequence length *n* is variable across instances.

I'm having trouble understanding two things here:

1. **What should the input look like?**
   I'm thinking of a 2D tensor with shape (number_of_x_inputs, x_dimension), where x_dimension is the length of a single vector $x$. Can such 2D tensor have a variable shape? I know tensors can have variable shapes for batch processing, but I don't know if that helps me here.
2. **How do I pass each input vector through the same transformation before feeding it to the RNN layer?**
   Is there a way to sort of extend for example a GRU so that an *f* layer is added before going through the actual GRU cell?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I hope this helps.

**Question 1:**

Vectors x1, x2... xn can have different shapes, but I'm not sure if the instances of x1 can have different shapes. When I have different shapes I usually pad the short sequences with 0s.

**Question 2:**

I'm not sure about extending a GRU, but I would do something like this:

```
x_dims = [50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
n = 5


def network():

    shared_f = Conv1D(5, 3, activation='relu')
    shated_LSTM = LSTM(10)

    inputs = []
    to_concat = []
    for i in range(n):
        x_i = Input(shape=(x_dims[i], 1), name='x_' + str(i))
        inputs.append(x_i)
        step1 = shared_f(x_i)
        to_concat.append(shated_LSTM(step1))

    merged = concatenate(to_concat)

    final = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(merged)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[final])
    # model = Model(inputs=[sequence], outputs=[part1])

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

m = network()
```

In this example, I used a Conv1D as the shared `f` transformation, but you could use something else (Embedding, etc.).